# Unable to browse or log in to Ubuntu host from Mac in local network

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a PC running Ubuntu 16.04 and I remote into it from my MBP with Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1

Sometimes I can't log in to it, not by using its hostname nor the IP address. I can't browse the Plex Media Server which is hosted by the same PC either. I just get a timeout error.

At the same time I can still browse the Internet with no issues at all. And I can still access my NAS by both IP address and hostname.

The connection to the Ubuntu host works if I turn the laptop wifi off and then I turn it back on.

BTW I also experienced a similar behaviour with my old 2010 MBP running El Capitan.

Has anyone had a similar issue before? If so - is there a fix?

Thanks.

Edit:

Now it's not working again so ping and ssh time out.

If I ssh from my MBP into my NAS, then from there I can SSH into the ubuntu box. So there's seems to be something odd going on between OS X and Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Update:

The ubuntu box is connected by Wifi 5G to an Asus RT-68U router.

The NAS is connected by ethernet to the same router.

The MBP is on WiFi.

I have turned off OS X's firewall too and still having the same issue.

Both the ubuntu server and the NAS have static IP addresses.

The MBP has usually a dynamic one but I've just now switched it to a static one. Still having the same issue.

I can ssh into the NAS and from there SSH into the ubuntu box, but can't do directly from the MBP into ubuntu. Also when logged in at ubuntu from the NAS if I ping the MBP it times out. It works fine when pinging it from the NAS.

Could there be some odd firewall rule filtering out traffic from each other? ufw is disable at the ubuntu box.

Comment: It sounds like there's some kind of packet forwarding issue. Like your Airport is noticing something about the device after running for a little bit, and then blocking connections since you can access it for a little bit once you turn your airport off. Are you able to plug directly into your server from your laptop and ping it?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - by airport I meant the Mac Wifi. So to answer your question: no, I can't ping it when there's no access. Actually when there's a connection the ping it's quite bad.

Comment: On the other hand pinging my Synology NAS from my laptop has no issues whereas pinging the ubuntu box is slow and with many timeouts.

Comment: Shouldn't really be anything off between osx and ubuntu, networking is all protocols. How does your ubuntu box hook to your home network, do you usually connect to your home network, and what is the topology of your network?